# SQL Query solution for 3 queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this 3 queries result

```
  z_id  |    data    | c_email_i
--------+------------+-----------
 276050 | 2012-03-30 |         1
 319536 | 2012-07-23 |         1
 190033 | 2010-01-18 |         1
 271987 | 2011-11-02 |         1
 319554 | 2012-08-21 |         1
 370881 | 2013-06-18 |         1

  z_id  |    data    | c_call_o
--------+------------+----------
 169456 | 2009-09-07 |        1
 148231 | 2009-09-25 |        2
 240949 | 2010-10-25 |        2
 119116 | 2009-01-09 |        2
 219206 | 2010-09-29 |        1
 243121 | 2010-11-02 |        1

  z_id  |    data    | c_call_i
--------+------------+----------
 169456 | 2009-09-07 |        1
 148231 | 2009-09-25 |        2
 240949 | 2010-10-25 |        2
 119116 | 2009-01-09 |        2
 219206 | 2010-09-29 |        1
 243121 | 2010-11-02 |        1
```

And I want to join it to result like this

```
 z_id |       data       | c_email_i | c_call_o | c_call_i
------+------------------+-----------+----------+----------
119116|     2009-01-09   |         0 |        2 |        2
169456|     2009-09-07   |         0 |        1 |        1
276050|     2012-03-30   |         1 |        0 |        0
...........
```

I tried to use UNION, but there was to many columns with (0 as fake_column) and i didnt like that. (but it was really fast)

On other side when I use left join (on dates and z_id tables) there is Query that takes like 40minutes with 800k results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And please show the queries you tried.

Comment: Postgres, forgot to mention it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

UNION ALL the three queries and do a GROUP BY:

```
select z_id, data, max(c_email_i), nax(c_call_o), max(c_call_i)
from
 (
   select z_id, data, c_email_i, null as c_call_o, null as c_call_i from...
   union all
   select z_id, data, null, c_call_o, null as c_call_i from...
   union all
   select z_id, data, null, null, c_call_i from...
 ) dt
group by z_id, data
```

Or put the queries in Derived Tables and join them, but if they're not returning the same z_id/data rows it's getting ugly with lots of COALESCE:

```
select
   coalesce(a.z_id, b.z_id, c.z_id),
   coalesce(a.data, b.data, c.data),
   coalesce(a.c_email_i, 0),
   coalesce(b.c_call_o, 0),
   coalesce(c.c_call_i, 0) 
from...
  (select ...) a
full outer join 
  (select ...) b
on a.z_id = b.z_id and a.data = b.data 
full outer join 
  (select ...) c
on coalesce(a.z_id,b.z_id) = c.z_id 
and coalesce(a.data,b.data) = c.data
```

Comment: I have more then 3 queries, so what would you prefer to use, because in first solution there is gonna be "select ss.z_id,ss.s_send_intime::date as Date, count(ss.s_id) as C_SMS_O, 0 as C_SMS_I, 0 as C_EMAIL_O, 0 as C_EMAIL_O_M, 0 as C_CALLS_O, 0 as C_CALLS_I, 0 as COLLECTION, 0 as C_SEARCHING, 0 as C_EMAIL_I, 0 as C_MAIL_O, 0 as C_MAIL_I" and I think it's too many 0 as column

Comment: I would still do the UNION ALL because using the FULL JOINs you have to do too many COALESCEs :-)  But regarding all those queries: are you accessing the same table or different ones? If it's the same you might be able to use a single query with some CASEs instead.

Comment: no it's already sql query from different places. But thanks you very much. I just wanted to be sure, that the union solutions it's not bad idea :]

Comment: You might also write and test both and compare performance. You probably write it only once, but execute it multiple times :-)

Comment: I already did and UNION was like 10x faster.. But I just didn't like too many (0 as columns), it looks to me unprofessional solution :D But I think that was just my feeling, nothing bad abotu it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like using `null as ...`, you can use this query:

```
with cte as (
    select 'c_email_i' as type, z_id, data, c_email_i as value from ...
    union all
    select 'c_call_o' as type, z_id, data, c_call_o as value from ...
    union all
    select 'c_call_i' as type, z_id, data, c_call_i as value from ...
)
select
    z_id, data,
    max(case when type = 'c_email_i' then value end) as c_email_i,
    max(case when type = 'c_call_o' then value end) as c_call_o,
    max(case when type = 'c_call_i' then value end) as c_call_i
from cte
group by z_id, data
```

or with subquery:

```
select
    z_id, data,
    max(case when type = 'c_email_i' then value end) as c_email_i,
    max(case when type = 'c_call_o' then value end) as c_call_o,
    max(case when type = 'c_call_i' then value end) as c_call_i
from (
    select 'c_email_i' as type, z_id, data, c_email_i as value from ...
    union all
    select 'c_call_o' as type, z_id, data, c_call_o as value from ...
    union all
    select 'c_call_i' as type, z_id, data, c_call_i as value from ...
) as c
group by z_id, data
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for advice, it works perfectly, but I discovered that 50% of databases where I need to use that its below 8.4 version.